# 2 POJO classes extends a Base class where each class maps to unique table. Why hibernate query creates Unknown column '' in 'field list error?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, inheritance, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 classes extending a base class.

Questions.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="question")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Questions{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String qid;

    @Column(name="addedtime")
    private String addedtime;

    @Column(name="qlang")
    private String qlang;

    @Id
    @Column(name="qid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getQid() {
        return qid;
    }

    public void setQid(String qid) {
        this.qid = qid;
    }

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getAddedtime() {
        return addedtime;
    }

    public void setAddedtime(String addedtime) {
        this.addedtime = addedtime;
    }

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getQlang() {
       return qlang;
    }

    public void setQlang(String qlang) {
       this.qlang = qlang;
    }
}
```

MCQ.java, TwoMarkQ.java  - all 2 classes extend Question.java.

MCQ.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MCQ")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class MCQ extends Questions implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="option_1")
    @Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
    private String option_1;

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getOption_1() {
        return option_1;
    }

    public void setOption_1(String option_1) {
        this.option_1 = option_1;
    }

    @Column(name="option_2")
    @Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
    private String option_2;

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getOption_2() {
        return option_2;
    }

    public void setOption_2(String option_2) {
        this.option_2 = option_2;
    }

}
```

TwoMarkQ.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TwoMarkQ")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class TwoMarkQ extends Questions implements Serializable{

    @Column(name="option_1")
    @Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
    private String option_1;

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getOption_1() {
        return option_1;
    }

    public void setOption_1(String option_1) {
        this.option_1 = option_1;
    }

    @Column(name="option_2")
    @Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
    private String option_2;

    @Access(value = AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public String getOption_2() {
        return option_2;
    }

    public void setOption_2(String option_2) {
        this.option_2 = option_2;
    }

}
```

All these 3 tables are mapped to unique tables in MySQL database.

Following are the results for show create table  for each table

```
create table `question` (
  `qid` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `addedtime` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `qtype` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `qlang` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`qid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

create table `MCQ`(
`qid` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`option_1` bigint(20) DEGAULT `0`,
`option_2` bigint(20) DEGAULT `0`,
PRIMARY KEY (`qid`),
CONSTRAINT `mcq_ibfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`qid`) REFERENCES `question` (`qid`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

create table `TwoMarkQ`(
`qid` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`option_1` bigint(20) DEGAULT `0`,
`option_2` bigint(20) DEGAULT `0`,
PRIMARY KEY (`qid`),
CONSTRAINT `two_markq_ibfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`qid`) REFERENCES `question` (`qid`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

In one of the DAO class, the SQL query goes like this.(The SQL query is against a derived class)

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select q.qid, q.qtype from Questions q where q.qlang=:lang ORDER BY q.addedtime ASC");
            query.setParameter("lang", lang);
            query.setFirstResult(startingRow).setMaxResults(10);
            result = (List<Questions>) query.list();
```

Error happens in the above line `result = (List<Questions>) query.list();`

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'qid' in 'field list'

Questions
1) Why am I getting   `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'addedtime' in 'field list'` and how to fix it?

Please help. Struck on this for 3 days.

PS: I'm using Hibernate version 4.3.5.Final

PS: This is the query generated

```
select questions0_.qid as col_0_0_, questions0_.qtype as col_1_0_ from ( select qid, addedtime, qlang, qtype, null as option_1, null as option_2 as class_ from MCQ union  select qid, addedtime, qlang, qtype, null as option_!, null as option_2 as class_ from TwoMarkQ)  questions0_ where questions0_.qlang=? order by questions0_.addedtime ASC limit ?
```

Since the `Query query = session.createQuery("select q.qid, q.qtype from Questions q where q.qlang=:lang ORDER BY q.addedtime ASC");` is on base class, it looks like it is making union with all the sub classes and sub classes doesn't have addedtime column. I'm just guessing.

Comment: You don't need to explain your entities. Just add the code so we can see it. Otherwise, no one can help you answer the question.

Comment: Yeah it would be helpful if you share the code for base entity and child entities.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Done sir.

Comment: Why do you cast result list to `List<Questions>` if you query for IDs (which is `string/varchar`)?

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko The query where clause is not targetting a single record from database. it could be a bunch of records. Hence, List<Questions>.

Comment: @user3705478 i mean why `List<Questions>`, not `List<String>`

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I plan to add few more select parameters down the line.

Comment: Why do you have @Inheritance in your subclasses, it should be enough for the super-class

Comment: @VladMihalcea Sir, I think only you can help me out. Please

Comment: Try to replicate it on the latest Hibernate ORM as explained [in this article](http://in.relation.to/2018/06/04/best-way-write-hibernate-orm-issue-test-case/). If you can replicate it. send a Pull Request. If you can't, then just upgrade Hibernate ORM to the latest version.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Sure sir, Will do it. But just realized that, when I make MCQ.java to NOT extend Questions, the generated hibernate query doesn't have MCQ in it.

Comment: Yes, that's by design. Check out the [User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class) for more details.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Could you answer this please https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/209888/126041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, This is how I resolved this issue.

The root cause is extending the base class Question.
I created a new class called Ques, which is implemented by Question.java, MCQ.java and TwoMarkQ.java

As per [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class)

We are provided with 3 options. 
`InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` or `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` or `InheritanceType.JOINED`

`JOINED:` is definitely not what I wanted. so it is a ruled out option.

```
SINGLE_TABLE:
```

The single table inheritance strategy maps all subclasses to only one database table.So this also leads to union of sub classes extending base class.

I still have following

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Polymorphism(type=PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
```

on Question.java, MCQ.java and TwoMark.java

```
TABLE_PER_CLASS
```

"When using polymorphic queries, a UNION is required to fetch the base class table along with all subclass tables as well." - So this is also a ruled out option.

Moreover I removed the foreign key references between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

then the error is due to the fact that in the table where hibernate is mapping there is no column, ie the field that usually defoult takes the name of the property.
The first question I want to ask you is the table is already present on the DB ?? why do you hibenate before doing anything you need to know with who you are mapping and in normal Hibernate use the classes let themselves be mapped to him.
So for when I can find out about hibernate to solve the problem you are redeeming you should map a single class with the one you have on the DB and then later map the "class of support" to your actual model.
Type a solution that is used when taking data from a server and the data does not reflect your current model.

I hope I have responded in line with your question and have been of help.

PS: Try to check if your db hibernate has not created other relational tabbells.

Comment: I updated the question details. Please take a look now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I try to post a bit of my code in hibernate version 4.x.x, why instead of writing the query do not try to use the Creteria and the Restrictions? the creteria gives you a list that you can decide if you want to return it already ordered, for example in my banal code of a person's search I had a generic DAO that implemet the query through the creteria.

```html
//DAO Generic
public List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) throws DAOException {
        try {
            Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
            for (Criterion c : criterion) {
                crit.add(c);
            }
            return crit.list();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new DAOException(ex);
        }
    }

//DAO person
    public List<Persona> findByCognome(String cognome) throws DAOException {
        try {
            Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Persona.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cognome", cognome).ignoreCase());
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("eta"));
            return criteria.list();
        } catch (DAOException ex) {
            throw new DAOException(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you posting multiple answers? This is not a discussion board.

Answer (score 0):

Change the inheritance strategy to JOINED. 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED).

You might need to add a column for question type in question table which is discriminator column for the type of question which you need to put as annotation on Questions class.

```
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
 @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "QUESTION_TYPE")
 public class Questions{
 .
 .
 }
```

And, in the child classes, you can give the discriminator value using @DiscriminatorValue annotation.

```
@DiscriminatorValue("MCQ")
public class MCQ extends Questions implements Serializable{
.
}
```

and

```
@DiscriminatorValue("TwoMarkQ")
public class TwoMarkQ extends Questions implements Serializable{
.
}
```

and remove @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) from child classes.